# Limit query is not working in codeigniter when using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to limit the result for pagination in foreach loop with the following query but instead of limiting I am getting all the results with the following query.

```
public function get_tags($limit, $start, $tag_id)
{    
    $snippetstagdata = $this->getDataOneColumn("snippets_tags","tag_id",$tag_id);
    foreach ($snippetstagdata as $getSnippet) {
        $snippet_id = $getSnippet->snippet_id;
        $this->db->where("id", $snippet_id);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('snippets');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result[] = $query->result();

    }

    $this->db->save_queries = false;

    return $result;
}
```

Whereas `getDataOneColumn`

```
public function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value)
{
    $this->db->where("$col1_name", $col1_value);
    $query = $this->db->get("$table");
    $result = $query->result();
    $this->db->save_queries = false;

    return $result;
}
```

> Updated

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more specific. Provide examples of what `getDataOneColumn` is returning as well as `result`. Then provide the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
public function get_tags($params = array(), $tag_id)
{   $result = array();
    $snippetstagdata = $this->getDataOneColumn("snippets_tags","tag_id",$tag_id);
    foreach ($snippetstagdata as $data) {
                $this->db->where('id',$data['snippet_id']);
        if(isset($params) && !empty($params))
        {
            $this->db->limit($params['limit'], $params['offset']);
        }
        $result[$data['snippet_id']] = $this->db->get('snippets')->result_array();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and

```
public function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table,array($col1_name=>$col1_value))->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to query your database with the help of the foreach loop is wrong. The correct approach would be using a join in the query:

from your function `getDataOneColumn()` you are only using the snippet_id values, which you can use to create the join:

```
public function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value, $limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->select("t1.*,t2.*")
             ->where("t1.$col1_name", $col1_value)
             ->join("snippets t2","t1.snippet_id=t2.id")
             ->limit($limit, $start);

    $query = $this->db->get("$table t1");
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
}
```

note: in your example `$tag_id=$col1_value`, so use whatever variable name fits better.

Your second function `get_tags()` is then not necessary at all.